# How do I fix these issues I get on a cloned site?

Tags: 9, deployment

I am maintaining a Drupal site using Docksal, at work. During the weekend, I wanted to work on it at home, from my computer.

- I cloned the repository

  ```bash
  git clone git@github.com:user/project.git folder
  ```
- I pulled up all the branches

  ```bash
  git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done
  git fetch --all
  git pull --all
  ```
- I ran the following commands

  ```bash
  fin init
  fin p start
  ```
- I imported the database

  ```bash
  fin db import /path/to_db/db.sql
  ```

On the site I ran from my computer, I have the following problems.

- The administration panel is collapsed and the tabs began to duplicate
- The Bartik theme is used as default theme instead of my sub-theme, which is based on the Bootstrpap5 theme

> [image]

How can I fix these issues?

Comment: How did you import the files?  Did you rebuild the cache?  I would rebuild the cache before exporting the db and then again after importing the db.

Comment: I'd also ensure that you checked out the correct branch locally. It's not uncommon for some projects to put production code in a branch other than the branch that's checked out during clone.